# How to create a Gcloud alert policy in command line with multiple conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to create a single alert policy for Cloud-Sql **instance_state** through Gcloud with multiple conditions.

If the instance is in **"RUNNABLE"** OR **"FAILED"** state for more than 5 minutes, then a alert should be triggered. I was able to create that in console and below is the screenshot:

[image]

Now I try the same using the command line and give this `gcloud` command:

```
    gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
         --display-name='Test Database State Alert ('$PROJECTID')' \
         --condition-display-name='Instance is not running for 5 minutes'\
         --notification-channels="x23234dfdfffffff" \
         --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_COUNT_TRUE"}' \
         --condition-filter='metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/instance_state" AND resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND (metric.labels.state = "RUNNABLE")' 
OR 'metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/instance_state" AND resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND (metric.labels.state = "FAILED")' \
         --duration='300s' \
         --if='> 0.0' \
         --trigger-count=1 \
         --combiner='OR' \
         --documentation='The rule "${condition.display_name}" has generated this alert for the "${metric.display_name}".' \
         --project="$PROJECTID" \
         --enabled
```

I am getting the error below in the **OR** part of the condition:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.create) unrecognized arguments:
  OR
  metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/instance_state" AND resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND (metric.labels.state = "FAILED")
```

Even if I put **( )** over the condition still it fails, also the **||** operator also fails.

What is the correct `gcloud` command for this? Also I want the structure of the alert policy to be similar to the one created in cloud-console as shown above.

Comment: Please have a look at the [command notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create): "**This command is currently in ALPHA and may change without notice**. If this command fails with API permission errors despite specifying the right project, **you may be trying to access an API with an invitation-only early access allowlist**." You could reach out to [Google Cloud Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to get early access. **It's not ready for production use**.

Comment: Thank you,  I have used gcloud alpha commands for a different api and succeeded in that

Comment: did you try to set your condition on only one line?

Comment: 'metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/instance_state" AND resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND (metric.labels.state = "RUNNABLE" OR metric.labels.state== "FAILEd")' -> this will create but it will not create the structure as shown in the picture and therefore i dont want to use this

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [gcloud alpha monitoring policies create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create), it appears that you can specify repeated (!) occurrences of:

```
[--aggregation=AGGREGATION --condition-display-name=CONDITION_DISPLAY_NAME --condition-filter=CONDITION_FILTER --duration=DURATION --if=IF_VALUE --trigger-count=TRIGGER_COUNT     | --trigger-percent=TRIGGER_PERCENT]
```

So I think you need to duplicate your `--condition-filter` with the `--combiner="OR"`, i.e.

```bash
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
--display-name='Test Database State Alert ('$PROJECTID')' \
--notification-channels="x23234dfdfffffff" \
--aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_COUNT_TRUE"}' \
--condition-display-name='RUNNABLE'\
--condition-filter='metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/instance_state" AND resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND (metric.labels.state = "RUNNABLE")' 
--duration='300s' \
--if='> 0.0' \
--trigger-count=1 \
--aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_COUNT_TRUE"}' \
--condition-display-name='FAILED'\
--condition-filter='metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/instance_state" AND resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND (metric.labels.state = "FAILED")' \
--duration='300s' \
--if='> 0.0' \
--trigger-count=1 \
--combiner='OR' \
--documentation='The rule "${condition.display_name}" has generated this alert for the "${metric.display_name}".' \
--project="$PROJECTID" \
--enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use [gcloud alpha monitoring policies conditions create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/conditions/create)  to append additional conditions.

```
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
    --notification-channels=projects/qwiklabs-gcp-04-d822dd6cd419/notificationChannels/2510735656842641871 \
    --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"}' \
    --condition-display-name='CPU Utilization >0.95 for 1m'\
    --condition-filter='metric.type="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization" resource.type="gce_instance"' \
    --duration='1m' \
    --if='> 0.95' \
    --display-name=' alert on spikes or consistantly high cpu' \
    --combiner='OR'

gcloud alpha monitoring policies list --format='value(name,displayName)'

gcloud alpha monitoring policies conditions create \
    projects/qwiklabs-gcp-04-d822dd6cd419/alertPolicies/1712202834227136574 \
    --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"}' \
    --condition-display-name='CPU Utilization >0.80 for 10m'\
    --condition-filter='metric.type="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization" resource.type="gce_instance"' \
    --duration='10m' \
    --if='> 0.80'
```

Duplicate `--condition-filter` clauses did not work for me. YMMV.